# How to ignore LAZY types dynamically on SpringBoot app?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private Set<Meal> meals = Collections.emptySet();

    //other fields, getters, setters, constructors
}
```

I'm getting my data with Spring Data:

```
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

}
```

I have REST-controller, which produces JSON data:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = RestaurantController.REST_URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8")
public class RestaurantController {
    static final String REST_URL = "/restaurants";

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public List<Restaurant> getOne(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

How to avoid including that LAZY data (set of Meals) to get them to a SQL request?
As I know I need to write a custom JacksonObjectMapper, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation in order to ignore the mapping of a field. Then you should do this:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
private Set<Meal> meals = Collections.emptySet();
```

**UPDATED**

Based what you want to do "**Ignore field dynamically when getting one or not getting alls**" you can use `@NamedEntityGraphs` annotation to specific what fields you want to join, then by using `@NamedEntityGraph` you specify the path and boundaries for a find operation or query and you should use in your custom `Repository` the `@EntityGraph` annotation who allows to customize the `fetch-graph` based what you want to do.

So you should add the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name="Restaurant.allJoins", includeAllAttributes = true),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name="Restaurant.noJoins")
})
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {

}

@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Restaurant.allJoins", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Override
    List<Restaurant> findAll();

    @EntityGraph(value = "Restaurant.noJoins", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    @Override
    Optional<Restaurant> findById(Integer id);

}
```

Comment: I need to ignore SERIALIZATION, not a View

Comment: Yes, you will do it with that annotation.

Comment: Sometimes I need to get them together. That annotation doesn't give it

Comment: do you mean to ignore serialization dynamically? let me know when you would like o ignore and when you don't.

Comment: When I get all the restaurants - I need to join Meals.
When I get only one restaurant - I don't need to join

Comment: Okay, I will update my answer then using other annotations.